# How to Customize (change) the Color Settings for MS Word Track Changes "Insertions" and "Deletions"

Tags: ms-word, office365, ms-office

The track-changes colors for "insertions" and "deletion" are pre-set from a selection menu, as shown below.

How can one change or customize these colors to different color settings in MSWord 2016 and later?

Most of the default colors are not readable on-screen or on-print and other colors (RGB) need to be used.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried already? A short Google action will tell you all you need to know to experiment with the color settings

Comment: @Boeryepes. There is no google solution I found for this (for years now) No luck !!

Comment: So neither change nor customize is possible? So this site not work? Application.options.InsertedTextColor = wdColorIndex.WdRed?

Comment: There could be a VBA code or function that programs or alter these color codes. I am not sure. The reason for the question.

Answer (score 1):

This code works:

```
Application.options.InsertedTextColor = wdColorIndex.WdRed
```

[image]

Check the other properties of Application.Options to make further customizations.

Comment: Thanks. The selection with `wdColorIndex....` is from the already predefined colors. In the above `.WdRed` is selected but I want that to say: light red or orange or a color shade not on the menu offered. i.e. being able to change the RGB values of the offered colours.

Comment: you can only embrace the possibilities at hand.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdcolorindex